# Von Kármán Vortices

Tags: plotting, fluid-dynamics

How may we vary vectors in

```
StreamPlot[{y, -Sin[x/2]}, {x, -4, 12}, {y, -4, 4}, 
  StreamColorFunction -> "Rainbow", AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

to obtain  a Von Kármán Vortex Street type vectored stream flow (alternating rotation sense in succeeding vortices)?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a Mathematica question ... it's more like a physics question.  Note: it's Kármán, not Kàrmàn.

Comment: At least there is a tag here, elsewhere it may not go through.

Comment: @Kattern : Thanks, I like to see  vector changes pictured on either side of, for example a fluttering flag. Please feel free to suggest how I should change my question with this aim in view.

Comment: Replace `StreamColorFunction  "Rainbow"` by `StreamColorFunction ->  "Rainbow"`.

Comment: @Kattern Is it possible to use Manipulate frames &c. to trace a few points  embedded on the streamline? It c/should give an impression of dry leaves floating in the  stream in  video (around obstacles at center but  free stream along x) caught by a stationary camera on  riverbank.

Comment: Narasimham, you seem to have obtained two excellent answers that seem to address the problem in your question. Have you considered officially accepting one of them?

Comment: No doubt both responded excellently...( esp. the image so beautifully depicts Strouhal type vortices that downed Tacoma Narrows bridge and so on ).  I want to * accept both*  of them, rules permitting.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Did you have something in mind like

```
StreamPlot[{(y - 2 Cos[x/4])  Cos[x/4], -Sin[x/4]}, {x, -4, 12}, 
  {y, -6, 6}, StreamColorFunction -> "Rainbow", AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Another plot, this one with net flow.

```
dy = 3; flow = 1; sv = 6; 
StreamPlot[{(y - dy Cos[x/4]) Exp[-(y - dy Cos[x/4])^2/sv]  Cos[x/4] + 
   flow (1 - Exp[-(y - dy Cos[x/4])^2/sv]), 
   -Sin[x/4] Exp[-(y - dy Cos[x/sv])^2/6]}, {x, -4, 18}, {y, -7, 7}, 
   StreamColorFunction -> "Rainbow", AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

The graphics choice suggested by chris makes the plot look even better.

```
dy = 3; flow = 1; sv = 6; 
LineIntegralConvolutionPlot[{{(y - dy Cos[x/4]) Exp[-(y - dy Cos[x/4])^2/sv] 
   Cos[x/4] + flow (1 - Exp[-(y - dy Cos[x/4])^2/sv]), 
   -Sin[x/4] Exp[-(y - dy Cos[x/sv])^2/6]}, {"noise", 500, 500}}, {x, -4, 18}, 
   {y, -6, 6}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, LineIntegralConvolutionScale -> 3]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes right, vorticity of alternating whirlpools are same sign, also here in youtube towards the last part. The streamlines should be in x-direction   always. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gq-sUhP3kDI

Comment: Gotta love the `LineIntegralConvolutionPlots` -- they're both cool and ugly at the same time.

Comment: Coool.. more than what I had expected.. Instead of brown another color combination could perhaps brighten it.

Comment: Add as an option the colors of your choice, such as `ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"`.  By the way, please accept this answer, if it meets your needs.

Comment: @chris  Who can say?  But, thanks.

Comment: I liked both, your vortex placements and the LICPlots. The combined effect is marvelous.. Anyways not against rules to accept both :)

Answer (score 7):

Or, almost directly from the documentation

```
LineIntegralConvolutionPlot[{{(y - 2 Cos[x/4]) Cos[x/4], -Sin[x/4]},
  , {"noise", 500, 500}}, {x, -4, 12}, {y, -6, 6}, 
 StreamColorFunction -> "BeachColors", AspectRatio -> Automatic,
 LightingAngle -> 0, LineIntegralConvolutionScale -> 3, Frame -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: "A Study in Cut Timber" :D

Comment: Annular rings.. more the merrier?